# JUnit 4 import a class of test cases (for functional tests)

Tags: java, junit

First, I understand JUnit is fundamentally a unit testing tool, but I hope I can achieve what I want with JUnit.

The tests I am writing with each test case acting more like a test step (at least conceptually). There are particular blocks of these steps that I would like to make common as they may fit into other work flows (yes, this is functional testing...).

Is what I seek possible?

Comment: Junit tests should be independent of each other.

Comment: Understood. I am breaking the best practices to try and implement functional tests. The reason being legacy infrastructure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you would like to introduce an interdependence between the unit tests. I think that this is most probably a bad idea as the unit test should be able to be run in any order and/or just one at a time. Introducing some implicit required order in your tests seems like the wrong path to take. If there is some process to follow then each test should be able to perform that process in isolation.

Comment: Yep, there will (already is) definitely be interdependence. For unit tests I agree with what you say, however I am dealing with functional tests. Of course this isn't the strength of JUnit and I should look into a different tool such as TestNG.  
  
edit: The reason I am hesitant is because there is a lot of infrastructure already in place using JUnit :(

Answer (score 0):

You can derive test classes from common vbase classes and annotate some methods with @Before / @After to be executed before and after each testcase ( this providing common setup / tear down  functionality ). You can also reuse some basic methods for recurring tasks.

Though I find mocking ( my favorite tool is jmockit ) more effective than setup methods and common functionlaity.   I need such common methods really seldom now.